# Holomorphic Hermitian metrics

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

Let $E\to M$ be a complex vector bundle. A hermitian metric $h$ on $E$ is a hermitian inner product on each fiber $E_{p},\, p\in M$. Suppose that $M$ is also a complex manifold and that $E$ is holomorphic. Under which conditions is $h$ in that case holomorphic? By that I mean that the local matrix representation of $h$ using a local (holomorphic) frame has holomorphic entries. I have never seen commented this condition in the literature, where, if I am not mistaken, one allows for "non-holomorphic" hermitian metrics on holomorphic vector bundles (or at least, that property is not discussed).

Thanks.

Comment: It is not so clear what you mean. If locally $h$ is given by $h_{\alpha\beta} v^\alpha, \otimes \overline{v^\beta}$, then $\overline{h_{\beta\alpha}} = h_{\alpha\beta}$. In particular, the diagonal must be real and cannot be holomorphic. (Unless it's a constant)

Comment: There is no restriction for $h$ being holomorphic itself. Being so will make all curvature terms $R_{i \bar{j} k \bar{l}}$ vanish.